# How Do I Add An Additional Column and Change The X-Axis To Log Scale On A Forest Plot Constructed With GGPlot2 and GridExtra?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I made a forest plot using the ggplot2 and gridextra packages, but I would like to add an extra column on the right side so that I can add the P-values.

Additionally, I would like to change the scale notation to log10.

Can anyone advise me on how to do this? I'm a novice, so any insight you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what the current code looks like with my data added:

```
  library(gridExtra)
    library(ggplot2)
      dat <- data.frame(
      Index = c(1, 2, 3, 4,5),
      label = c("All", "Her2+", "LumA", "LumB", "TNBC"),
     HR = c(0.2,0.23, 0.11, 0.22,0.2),
     LL = c(0.14, 0.08, 0.06, 0.1,0.11),
     UL = c(0.28, 0.68, 0.21, 0.5,0.35),
     CI = c("(0.14 - 0.28)", "(0.08 - 0.68)", "(0.06 - 0.21)", "(0.1 - 0.5)", "(0.11 - 0.35)"), 
     P_Value = c("<0.0001", "0.0065", "<0.0001", "<0.0001", "0.0001")
   )
   plot1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(y = Index, x = HR)) + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10')   + 
     geom_point(shape = 18, size = 5) +  
     geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = LL, xmax = UL), height = 0.25) +
     geom_vline(xintercept = 1, color = "red", linetype = "dashed", cex = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
     scale_y_continuous(name = "", breaks=1:5, labels = dat$label, trans = "reverse") +
     xlab("Hazard Ratio (Log10)") + 
     ylab(" ") + 
     theme_bw() +
     theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"))
plot1

table_base <- ggplot(dat, aes(y=label)) +
  ylab(NULL) + xlab("  ") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(color="white", hjust = -3, size = 25), ## This is used to help with alignment
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        plot.background = element_blank())
tab1 <- table_base + 
  labs(title = "space") +
  geom_text(aes(y = rev(Index), x = 1, label = sprintf("%0.1f", round(HR, digits = 2))), size = 4) + ## decimal places
  ggtitle("HR")
tab2 <- table_base +
  geom_text(aes(y = rev(Index), x = 1, label = CI), size = 4) + 
  ggtitle("95% CI")
lay <-  matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3), nrow = 1)
grid.arrange(plot1, tab1, tab2, layout_matrix = lay)
```

Code source: https://github.com/mbounthavong/Forest-plots-in-R/blob/main/RMarkdown_code

Comment: I tried adding a "tab3" and adjusting the matrix, but received an error

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
forest <- ggplot(dat, aes(y = Index, x = HR)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 18, size = 5) +  
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = LL, xmax = UL), height = 0.25) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, color = "red", linetype = "dashed", cex = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "", breaks=1:5, labels = dat$label, trans = "reverse", expand = expansion(add = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10')   + 
  xlab("Hazard Ratio (Log10)") + 
  ylab(" ") + 
  theme_classic()
    
tab <- ggplot(dat, aes(y = Index)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0, label = sprintf("%0.1f", round(HR, digits = 2))), size = 4) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1, label = CI), size = 4) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 2, label = P_Value), size = 4) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'reverse', expand = expansion(add = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 0:2, labels = c('HR', 'CI', 'P-value'), 
    position = 'top', expand = expansion(add = 0.5)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = 'bold'))
  
library(patchwork)
forest + tab + plot_layout(ncol = 2, widths = c(3, 1))
```

[image]